# reactJS: How to get rid of findDOMNode in this case?

Tags: reactjs

I came up with a working solution to add a class or remove a class based on previous props and next props, but it uses `findDOMNode` which should be avoided according to best practices. I have looked through some examples here https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/issues/678, but I cannot see the easiest way to eliminate the `findDOMNode` in my case since it is inside of a class lifecycle method.

```
export class Price extends React.Component {
  componentWillUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    console.log(this);
    if (nextProps.price !== this.props.price) {
      var element;
      if (nextProps.price >= this.props.price) {
        ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this).classList.add("upTick");
        element = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this);
        setTimeout(function() {
          element.classList.remove("upTick");
        }, 10000);
      } else {
        ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this).classList.add("downTick");
        element = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this);
        setTimeout(function() {
          element.classList.remove("downTick");
        }, 10000);
      }
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <span className="price">
        {this.props.price.toFixed(2)}
      </span>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could always use state on the component to set "shouldShowUpTick" and then conditionally add that class in the render method based on the state - then you just have to set the timeout to add/remove the various boolean states and the conditional classNames - classnames ([npm module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames)) is quite good for this "conditional classes" approach.

```js
import classnames from 'classnames';

export class Price extends React.Component {
  componentWillUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    if (nextProps.price !== this.props.price) {
      if (nextProps.price >= this.props.price) {
        this.setState({ shouldShowUpTick: true }, () => {
          setTimeout(function() {
            this.setState({ shouldShowUpTick: false }));
          }, 10000);
      } else {
        this.setState({ shouldShowDownTick: true }, () => {
          setTimeout(function() {
            this.setState({ shouldShowDownTick: false }));
          }, 10000);
      }
    }
  }

  render() {
    const classNames = classnames('price', {
      'up-tick': this.state.shouldShowUpTick,
      'down-tick': this.state.shouldShowDownTick
    });

    return (
      <span className={ classNames }>
        {this.props.price.toFixed(2)}
      </span>
    );
  }
}
```